# Manipulating data in multiple tables & EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I need to delete data from multiple tables for a single user operation. I can delete from respective entities in the context and call SaveChanges. This makes sure there is only one connection but there will be one network call to the DB for each deletion. Is there any way to improve performance here?

We can use stored procedure but the context will not have updated entity data after the SP execution (unless I recreate the context which again establishes a new connection to the DB). So, for this reason, SP is ruled out.

Note: delete operation is just for illustration purpose but I have few other operations that involve multi table updates (like moving data from one table to another table)

Thanks

Comment: Moving data from one table to another, isn't updating data. It is Inserting and deleting.

Comment: can you share your EF query ?

Comment: Use a single context and do your processing. Afterwards, call `context.SaveChanges()`. This will execute the generated script on the database. SaveChanges should only be called once in a single operation.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I know it is insert & delete but from user point of view it is updating, so I used that word. My main point is improving performance by having few calls to DB.

Comment: @Ephraim Recreating the DbContext is the suggested approach and I had already mentioned that. I am trying to know other possibilities. With every new DbContext object, we will establish new connection and I am worried there.

Comment: @CHEMBETIARAVIND by single context I did not mean a static or controller-shared context. Let's say you have a method, create the context there and do all necessary changes in each `DbSet` as needed. Afterwards, call the `context.SaveChanges()` once. Sharing a context with multiple controllers or API methods will make you prone to threading issues. That's your best bet.

Comment: @Ephraim That is what I am doing right now by making use of StructureMap because of threading issues and dispose of the DbContext once the operation or set of operations are done. But the question is - for each operation we are making a network call and I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: @CHEMBETIARAVIND what do you mean by one network call for each deletion? Can you post your code for your current implementation? There would be one network call for each `SaveChanges()`

Comment: @Ephraim Ok, now I think I misunderstood SaveChanges part. What I thought was, when we call that API, EF will send queries to DB as per entities tracked changes. As there could be dependencies on entities, I thought, for better and effective tracking, EF would be sending queries to DB one by one. If that is not the case, then no problem.

Comment: @CHEMBETIARAVIND That is not the case. It will execute all the necessary changes on the database in a batch-like manner meaning it will only execute the queries once. :)

Comment: @Ephraim OK, thanks for the confirmation.